# How can I combine puppeteer-extra with express?

Tags: express, puppeteer

I'm trying to combine puppeter-extra with express. For each request I will be able to load a different plugin, for example:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { useStealth } = req.query
    if(useStealth) puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(parameters..)
    const page = await browser.newPage();
})
```

The problem is that, when I send the first request with query useStealth, it will set in node cache puppeteer-extra to use StealthPlugin, so the others next requests will use it. I tried to solve this problem by clear node cache, it works but it's a problem for concorrent requests. My code to try to solve it (But it has the concorrent request problem):

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('puppeteer-extra')];
puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
```

Is there anyway to clean `puppeteer.use` function ? (So, It would be a new instance of puppeteer-extra per request)

Thanks!